# Undefined reference to functions while linking to static library

Tags: c, static-libraries, static-linking, dynamic-linking, dynamic-library

I'm including `X.a` static library to my code and `X.a` requires `a.so` library , so do I need to include `X.a` only or do I need to include both libaries to my code?

I have tried including the only `X.a` for my code but it is not finding the definition of the functions which are in `a.so`.which is used by `X.a`.

Comment: Show the actual build command [in your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61401809/edit).

Comment: And show also how you include the `.h` files. `.a` and `.so` are for the linker, `.h` are needed by the compiler. So, if in your program you are using a.so symbols, you may need to include a.h as well.

Comment: You may also have answered your own question. If `X.a` requires `a.so`, what makes you think you can get by without it? It may use an `a.so` function in the initialization of whatever comes from `X.a`. That really depends on what both do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> do I need to include X.a only or do I need to include both libaries to my code?

You don't "include" libraries in your code, you *link* them in.

When you link against `X.a`, the linker copies used parts of the library into your executable.

When you link against `a.so`, the linker makes a note that `a.so` is required at runtime, and (if you are using versioned symbols) which versions of symbols from `a.so` must be present at runtime, but doesn't copy any code from `a.so` into your executable. However, `a.so` is still required on the link time.

There are ways to link an executable without `a.so`, but they are best left to experts (there are too many possible gotcha's with that approach).

Comment: If I create the x.so instead of x.a and open library at run time using dlopen(), is it necessary to link a.so to my code

Comment: @maheshhegde If you `dlopen` the `x.so`, then it's not necessary to link your executable against `x.so` (but it will be necessary to restructure your code to use `dlsym` instead of direct calls). I don't see what that has to do with your question though.